# Convergence issue for GLMM

Tags: convergence, glmm

I analyzed reaction time data using GLMM. In order to find the best model based on random effect via model comparison, I incrementally added the random intercept and random slope of four factors (and each factor was mean-centered deviation) for each subject, as shown here below:

```
model1 <- glmer(RT ~ A_recode * B_recode * C_recode * D_recode + (1|Subject), 
                                          data=Mydata, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
model2 <- glmer(RT ~ A_recode * B_recode * C_recode * D_recode + (1|Subject) + (1+A_recode|Subject), 
                                          data=Mydata, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
model3 <- glmer(RT ~ A_recode * B_recode * C_recode * D_recode + (1|Subject) + (1+A_recode|Subject) +
               (1+B_recode|Subject),  data=Mydata, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
model4 <- glmer(RT ~ A_recode * B_recode * C_recode * D_recode + (1|Subject) + (1+A_recode|Subject) +
               (1+B_recode|Subject) + (1+C_recode|Subject) ,  data=Mydata, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
model5 <- glmer(RT ~ A_recode * B_recode * C_recode * D_recode + (1|Subject) + (1+A_recode|Subject) +
               (1+B_recode|Subject) + (1+C_recode|Subject) +  (1+D_recode|Subject) ,  data=Mydata, family = gaussian(link = "log"))

anova(model1, model2, model3, model4, model5)
```

The given results are here below:
[image]

The results look like a bit weird, as the Chisq value for the model 2, 4, 5 is 0, and the p value for these three models are 1, seems implying that the three models are the same; whereas other values are different, seems indicating they are actually different however.
I thus also checked the model summary, here's the result for the first model:
[image]

According to the fixed effect results as shown here above, the output value looks rational, however, I got the warning that:
"convergence code:0
Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue

- Rescale variables?"

Based on above results, I'm a bit confused, are the results reliable? or is there something wrong with my model? how can I fix the warning issue?
Your any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't put pictures of output in your post - please put the actual output text. Also please include the random effectt part of the output. Why are you trying to fit so many random slopes ? What kind of variable is `RT` ? Why are you using a GLMM and not a LMM ?